# How to mock requests methods called dynamically using getattr

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, python-requests

I have class which called requests method using getattr like this:

```
import requests

class CustomRequests(object):
     def __init__(self):
         pass

     def _do_requests(self, method='GET', url='', expected_status=200):
         make_request = getattr(requests, method.lower())
         url = url if url else 'http://example.com'

         try:
            response = make_request(method, url=url)
            except response.exceptions.RequestException as exception:
                raise exception
         if response.status_code != expected_status:
            raise ValueError

    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self._do_requests(method='GET', *args, **kwargs)
```

I am trying to test the api using mock and responses lib like this:

```
import responses

@responses.activate
def test_get_method(self):
    responses.add('GET', url='http://test_this_api.com', status=200)
    custom_request = CustomRequest()
    response_data = custom_request.get(method='GET')
    AssertIsNotNone(response_data)
```

Is there any better or right way to test this method.
Getting this error:

```
    message = message.format(**values)
KeyError: 'method'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no need to use `getattr`. `requests.get`, `requests.post`, etc. are just convenience methods for [`requests.request`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/api/#requests.request), which lets you pass the HTTP method as a parameter:

```
requests.request('GET', url) # equivalent to requests.get(url)
```

Also:

- Your `try`/`except` is pointless, since all you do is re-raise the exception.
- It doesn't make sense to raise a `ValueError` when the response status doesn't match what you expected. `ValueError` is for ["when a built-in operation or function receives an argument that has the right type but an inappropriate value."](https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.ValueError) Create your own exception class, e.g. `UnexpectedHTTPStatusError`.
- Since the whole point of your `CustomRequests` class seems to be to raise an exception when the status code of the response doesn't match what the user expected, your tests should assert that an exception was actually raised with [`assertRaises()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertRaises).

Comment: Thanks @ThisSuitIsBlackNot. Thanks for all the points under 'Also:'. I just made up those Try/Except as couldn't able to find better example to write. In my code I am exactly doing the same thing as you pointed out. Let me try out if that works while I mock the requests using responses.